# How to implement Fernet encryption with AES 256

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, aes, python-cryptography

I'm currently using [Fernet](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/) encryption which uses AES 128 keys. However my client requires using AES 256. I'm not very familiar with cryptography but here is what I understood so far.

Fernet needs a 256 bits key that is splitted in half. First half is the signing key, second one is the encryption key. As they are 128 bits long it is AES 128.

Would it be enough to double the input key and modify the implementation like below to get AES 256 ?

```
class Fernet(object):
    def __init__(self, key, backend=None):
        if backend is None:
            backend = default_backend()

        key = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(key) # Here 512 bits long instead of 256

        self._signing_key = key[:16] # double this
        self._encryption_key = key[16:] # double this
        self._backend = backend
```

Comment: The 128 and 256 in AES-128 and AES-256 are the number of *bits*, not *bytes* in the key. As the Fernet documentation states: "Fernet uses ... AES in CBC mode with a 128-bit key for encryption; using PKCS7 padding."

Comment: Translation mistake, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could double the binary input, the input before the key was base 64 encoded. If the result is 256 bit secure depends on how the *key is generated*. So yes, it is possible to double the size *check* on the key, but that doesn't say much. If the input key material is 512 bits with a security level of 512 bits then yes, then splitting the key is fine.

Personally I would recommend (and I have recommended it in the past to Fernet) to use HKDF to derive the two keys instead of just splitting the key in two. I cannot see how the key is generated, but if it is generated by PBKDF2 - which Fernet does use to create keys from passwords - then PBKDF2 may require double the amount of work to generate 512 bits, while the attacker will only have to generate 256 bits to perform an attack (and therefore perform half of the work).

Note that using base64 encoding is not great for keys as strings are hard to delete from memory in most runtimes; it's much better if the keys are stored in a *key store*.

Comment: Your answer and the question seem unrelated. I'm confused.

Comment: OP says he wants AES-256. He can't get it because Fernet doesn't support it. You seem to be talking about something unrelated.

Comment: Ah, whatever, the person that asked the question seemed to get it.

Comment: First thanks for the detailed answer. However, I'm a bit confused by the comment "Fernet doesn't support it (AES 256)". If I use a 512 bits input key (not generated with Fernet but from the client keyring) and derive it with HKDF, a 256 bits key will be passed to the AES algorithm so I well get AES 256, wont I ? Sorry if I sound unclear, I've always felt uncomfortable with encryption.

Comment: Right. You can certainly derive a 512 bit key, then split it up into two 256 bit halves. How much security there is depends of course on the input. But even if that is 256 bits of security then the two keys should still be at around 256 bits of security, i.e. no decrease from what you already had... Feeling unclear around encryption - or at least feeling defensive - around encryption is exactly what is required. You need to be slightly paranoid, otherwise you'll stumble into problems. Doing a course like Cryptography I from Dan Boneh is a good idea though :)

Comment: By the way, I finally understand what he was asking and you were right, as usual.

Answer (score 1):

The [Fernet Specification](https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md) is to use AES-128. If you modify the algorithm to use AES-256, then you would no longer be using [Fernet](https://github.com/fernet/spec). If it's a requirement that you use both Fernet and AES-256, I would recommend encrypting your payload independently using AES-256 and then applying the Fernet algorithm to the result. This essentially encrypts it again using AES-128.